# Belgium to UK travel with my wife through Calais/UK border

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, family

I have a Belgium family member residence card that's valid for five years. Together with my German wife and one-year old son, I want to visit the UK for a weekend.

Do I need a visa?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Belgium Family card"? What is your citizenship? Is your wife a German citizen and would she be coming with you? Voting to close as unclear until you specify.

Comment: @Dorothy your edit makes the Q easier to read and clearer but we have no idea whether the points you made are actually the OPs intention. I would personally prefer the question remained closed until OP comes back to clarify, potentially even undoing your edit as it gives the impression of a  question that was not there before in its current form. Just my two cents.

Comment: No, you do not Need a visa, your family card and passport is enough. When the question is re-opened, I'll explain exactly

Comment: I don't see how this is unclear. OP's English is mangled, yes, but to me it is perfectly clear judging by the original version that he's asking whether a family card provides a visa exemption for the UK

Comment: @Crazydre if it is reopened, this question should be reclosed as a duplicate of [Do I need a visa to visit the UK with my EU partner?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/90030/19400)  And you will learn there that the passport and residence card are *not* enough; a marriage certificate is also required.

Comment: @phoog In actuality you only need to be *able* to prove your family relationship, in case it comes into doubt: the basic requirement is to present the passport and residence card

Comment: @Crazydre the conclusion you describe follows from the directive, but not from the information given by the UK authorities. Since the UK authorities are the ones in control of entry into the UK, it seems prudent to follow their stated requirements.

Comment: @phoog On the other hand, the info the UK government has provided to IATA mentions nothing of a marriage certificate being a requirement. And I personally know a couple of cases of the GOV.UK website being inconsistent with actual practice at the border.

Comment: @Crazydre okay, but even you say that one must be "able" to prove one's family relationship. Even if the officers don't always ask for such proof, failing to carry it creates a very real risk of being refused entry. There's no predictable circumstance under which it would definitely be unnecessary. Therefore, it should be considered required. Presumably that is why gov.uk indicates as much. Also, I'm sorry to say, in the current climate, some people will be much more likely to receive extra scrutiny than others, and I suspect the asker of this question is in the former group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56077/discussion-between-phoog-and-crazydre).